# Getter & Setter not working properly in frontside and backend

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    import { getCount } from './lib/count';
</script>

<button
    on:click={() => {
        console.log(getCount());
    }}
>
    get Count
</button>

<button
    on:click={async (e) => {
        await fetch('/api', {});
    }}
>
    call API
</button>
```

api/+server.js

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { getCount, setCount } from '../lib/count';
export function GET() {
    setCount(1);
    console.log(getCount());

    return json(0);
}
```

lib/count.js

```
let count = 0;
export const getCount = () => count;
export const setCount = (newCount) => {
    count = newCount;
};
```

[Front: click getCount after click call API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lqHH.png)

[Backend: console.log from backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W379L.png)

**Why the variable updated through the server using a getter on the front end, the update doesn't seem to take place?**

I'm posting this question because I can't even grasp keywords related to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on the server and the code in the browser are not referring to the same thing. Each is creating a separate instance that is independent of the other.

You have to transfer/change state via mechanism like [`load` functions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) and [form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions).

Also, you should generally avoid global state on the server as it would be shared between all users. In some deployment environments there may also be separate instances of the same state as code is being executed multiple times in parallel to handle more requests. The most common way to persist state would be by using a database instead.

When manipulating state on the client, getter and setter functions are to be avoided when using Svelte, as they break reactivity. For local component state just use variables directly, for state that is extracted or otherwise sometimes disconnected from components, use [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store).